# Row Number for a view where the number is not affected by the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

SQL Server 2008

I have a view with numerous rows, where it could also be possible to have the exact row multiple times. I already tried ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY col1 ) as row_id but ran into a problem:

When using a JOIN or a WHERE clause, the row_ids are dynamically adjusted to the new result set. What I need instead is the row_id to represent the row_id value which is given for that row in the view WITHOUT any JOIN or WHERE clauses.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I added an example, should have done it before posting.

Without WHERE clause:

> SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY col1 ) as row_id, result.* 
>   FROM
>   (
>
> > SELECT 'Adam' col1, 'West' col2
> >     UNION ALL
> >     SELECT 'Adam' col1, 'Cole' col2
> >     UNION ALL
> >     SELECT 'Adam' col1, 'West' col2
> >     UNION ALL
> >     SELECT 'Danny' col1, 'West' col2
>
> ) result

Result:

```
row_id  col1    col2
1       Adam    Cole
2       Adam    West
3       Adam    West
4       Danny   West
```

Now when I use the WHERE clause

> SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY col1 ) as row_id, result.* 
>   FROM
>   (
>
> > SELECT 'Adam' col1, 'West' col2
> >     UNION ALL
> >     SELECT 'Adam' col1, 'Cole' col2
> >     UNION ALL
> >     SELECT 'Adam' col1, 'West' col2
> >     UNION ALL
> >     SELECT 'Danny' col1, 'West' col2
>
> ) result
>   WHERE col2='West'

Result:

```
row_id  col1    col2
1       Adam    West
2       Adam    West
3       Danny   West
```

Desired result:

```
row_id  col1    col2
2       Adam    West
3       Adam    West
4       Danny   West
```

Comment: Please post your table structure, some sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate the row numbers in a subquery.  Those are not affected by a `join` or `where` clause in the outer query:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over order by col1) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) as YourTableWithRowNumber
join    OtherTable
on      YourTableWithRowNumber.id = OtherTable.YourTableId
where   YourTableWithRowNumber.col1 not like '%excludeme%'
```

Comment: This really could be it - I'll give it a try, Thanks!